# How can I bring back the "short survey" invitation?

Tags: support

Less than a hour ago, I logged into the site and saw two "short survey" invitations on the page:

1. a bar on the top of the page;
2. a small pop-up rectangle near the bottom-left corner of the page.

I wished to take the survey, but I didn't like that "pop-up rectangle" at the bottom, therefore I started with clicking "x" inside of it. Unfortunately, that rectangle at the bottom disappeared together with the bar at the top (which was more appealing to me).

I logged out of the site and cleared the cookies and then logged in again. Unfortunately, no survey invitation bars are displayed this time.

IMHO, there should be an option to bring back the short survey invitation.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see any buttons on any page for the survey link, but you can use the following links for the survey as I copied the link.

- [Bottom Popup Link](https://stackoverflow.com/survey/site-satisfaction/redirect/?source=sidebar)
- [Top of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/survey/site-satisfaction/redirect/)

Note: Currently [these links are not working](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389796/take-our-short-survey-link-redirecting-to-home-page), but hopefully it will be solved soon.

I hope it will help.