# "Take our short survey" link redirecting to home page

Tags: discussion, support

The following links are not working for survey.

https://stackoverflow.com/survey/site-satisfaction/redirect

https://stackoverflow.com/survey/site-satisfaction/redirect/?source=sidebar

Did you get same problem?

[image]